# devise/omniauth login with linkedin - validation failed: email can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth

1. Validate failed in LinkedIn sign_up using rails omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 gem.
2. Here my code.

   ```
   elsif auth.provider == 'linkedin'
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.first_name = auth.info.name
       user.last_name = auth.info.name
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.save!
   ```

Comment: Inspect `user` & `auth.info.email`

Comment: Also ensure that you request email in the scope. It should be something like `r_emailaddress` but I'm not sure if this one is not outdated already

Comment: Thank for replay : I think i'm created developer account using same email in multiple account like gmail, facebook, github.  Now database email field is validates but i'm login multiple sites in a single gmail then error. and add this validation in my user model.                                                                    
 validates :email, uniqueness: true